# Is it possible to not repeat Rails ActiveRecord where condition arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails ActiveRecord `where` that looks like this:

```
Things.where('blahs.foo_id = ? OR bar_id = ?', user.id, user.id)
```

I want `user.id` to be used in place of the two `?`'s. Is there a way to not repeat it like I've done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just use a hash instead of repeat variables.

```
Things.where('blahs.foo_id = :user_id OR bar_id = :user_id', :user_id => user.id)
```

Comment: So much more elegant! I was sure it existed!